# ng-bind-html directive removes style attribute when renders

Tags: html, angularjs

When I write

```
 <div ng-bind-html="slideContent"></div>
```

where

```
    this.$scope.slideContent = 
this.$sce.trustAsHtml("<img src='1.jpg' style='width: 231px'></img>");
```

angular removes style attribute, so image has initial size.
What do you think? How I can avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/hu0ZxW2b5ZebWlFKR6WM?p=preview

Comment: yes. but in context of my project it's not work. I don't know why

Answer (score 11):

Note that `ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been removed from Angular.
I would rather create a filter, instead of adding a function to scope in order to avoid scopes pollution and improve the code reusability:

```
app.filter('unsafe', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (input) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
}]);
```

There is no need to write anything in the scope, just add the filter on the template:

```
<div ng-bind-html="resultList.section | unsafe"></div>
```

Comment: I was searching for this solutions

Answer (score 9):

use ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(resultList.section)" in html tag
and put this function controller

```js
$scope.trustedHtml = function (plainText) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(plainText);
}
```

```html
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(resultList.section)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` instead. but be careful to not use it with input provided by users.